# Convert the comma separated cell contents to multiple cells in same columns

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a excel file with the following kind of data.

```
Pink_Floyd,Beatles,Pearl_Jam,Porcupine_Tree 5.56
```

The data comprises of same kind of rows.The numeric value is in next cell.
I want to convert it into the following format-

```
Pink_Floyd 5.56
Beatles    5.56
Pearl_Jam  5.56
Porcupine_Tree 5.56
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Pink_Floyd,Beatles,Pearl_Jam,Porcupine_Tree', 'Beatles'], 
                   'B': [5.56, 10.0]})
print (df)
                                             A      B
0  Pink_Floyd,Beatles,Pearl_Jam,Porcupine_Tree   5.56
1                                      Beatles  10.00
```

---

```
s = (df.pop('A').str.split(',', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename('A'))

df = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)[['A','B']]
```

**Explanation**:

1. Extract column `A` by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html)
2. Then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to `DataFrame`
3. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
4. Then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove first level of `MultiIndex`
5. Change column name by `rename`
6. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original and if necessary change order of columns by `list`

Or create new `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
from itertools import chain

a = df['A'].str.split(',')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : list(chain.from_iterable(a.values.tolist())), 
    'B' : df['B'].values.repeat(a.str.len())
})
```

---

```
print (df)
                A      B
0      Pink_Floyd   5.56
1         Beatles   5.56
2       Pearl_Jam   5.56
3  Porcupine_Tree   5.56
4         Beatles  10.00
```

Comment: okay, I have a datafile of 3000 rows, how to assign header as you have added?

Comment: What return `df = pd.read_excel(file)`, `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: It is returning `Index(['second_final', 'Unnamed: 1'], dtype='object')` ,second_final is the name of the file

Comment: @Mark - You can set columns names like `df.columns = ['A','B']`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I have another rookie doubt too, how to improve my intuition over pandas and numpy too, I am finding it hard to build intuition for it

Comment: @Mark - Hard question, maybe some tutorials should help, I like [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas) a lot.